# Can an EMV bank card be used to digitally sign documents?

Tags: digital-signature

Bank accounts are bound to an identity. Can bank cards be used in the same way as https://www.identrust.com/certificates/document-signing ?

Comment: APDU in EMV has specific format which is known to EMV card. If data fields have arbitrary length and missing fields, card will terminate the transaction.

Comment: Looks like https://www.openscdp.org/scripts/tutorial/emv/SDA.html describes the process.

Comment: No. SDA ensures the authenticity of ICC data. SDA card takes no input from terminal. SDA and DDA are obsolete now. Modern cards use CDA. For arbitrary data signing you have use custom smart card.